# Assigning grade and adding that as new column

Tags: r

I want to grade the students on the basis of score . My data frame

```
Students Subject1 Subject2 subject3  Total    
S1      20       10       15         45      
S2      10       10       12         32      
S3      5        10       10         25      
S4      8        10       15         33      
S5      6        5        5          16
S6      10      -5       -5          0
```

I want to check if the Total is `>30` then assign P , if `<30` then A, else `0`

Output

```
student Subject1 Subject2 subject3  Total   Grade
    S1      20       10       15       45      P
    S2      10       10       12       32      P
    S3      5        10       10       25      F
    S4      8        10       15       33      P
    S5      6        5        5        16      F
    S6      10      -5       -5        0       0
```

i tried this code

```
df$Grade <- ifelse(df$Total==0, '0',
                                    ifelse(df$Total < 30, 'A',ifelse(df$Total >30,'P')))
```

But i think its not a correct way.

```
Error in ifelse(df$Total == 0, "0", ifelse(df$Total <  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'no' in selecting a method for function 'ifelse': Error in ifelse(df$Total < 30, "A", ifelse(df$Total >  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'no' in selecting a method for function 'ifelse': Error in ifelse(df$Total > 30, "P") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: I think the description, expected result and the code is not matching

Comment: I want `P` for `>30`, `F`  for `<30` else `0`

Comment: The logic is not clear.  Do you want 0 values for `Total == 30` or is it `Total==0`?

Comment: What will be the Grade if Total is less than 0?

Comment: In that case you need three nested `ifelse`.  I would use `cut` or `findInterval` for multiple categories.  Please be specific when you post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the `cut` function:

```
cut(mydf$Total, c(-Inf, 0, 30, Inf), labels = c(0, "F", "P"))
## [1] P P F P F
## Levels: 0 F P
```

The above basically says to categorize scores from `-Inf` to 0 as "0", scores between 0 and 30 as "F", and scores between 30 and `Inf` as "P". Thus, if your vector of scores were `c(0, 12, 30, 31, 12, 0, 40)`, you would get:

```
cut(c(0, 12, 30, 31, 12, 0, 40), c(-Inf, 0, 30, Inf), labels = c(0, "F", "P"))
## [1] 0 F F P F 0 P
## Levels: 0 F P
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,grade:=ifelse(Total==0,"0",ifelse(Total>=30,"P",ifelse(Total %in% 1:30,"A","N")))]
```

You didn't stated what the expected `grade` should be in case `Total==30`, hence I coded it as P, you may want to correct it as needed.